# How to eliminate blank elements from a list in Angular

Tags: angular, list, ngfor

I have this:

```
 <ul *ngIf="this.sessionVar.emptySession == false" class="listTracks" data-simplebar>
        <li class="track-item" *ngFor="let item of tracksInSession; let i = index">
          <a href="#" *ngIf="this.favSort == false && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true" [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
          <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isImported == true && item.isFavorite == false && this.favSort == false && this.impSort == true && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
          <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isImported == true && item.isFavorite == true && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == true && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
          <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isFavorite == true && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
          <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isImported == false && this.favSort == false && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == true" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
          <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isFavorite == true && item.isImported == false && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == true" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I am trying to print a filtered array, but when i apply the filter and the element does not respect the if condition i have a blank list element, like in next image.

[image]

Comment: This is wrong => `*ngIf="item.isImported == true` and it should be written as => `*ngIf="item.isImported` for truthy and `*ngIf="!item.isImported` to check the false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if your li-element is necessary (I assume, that this element produces the space between your list items). You can not use a ngIf on the li-element itself, because there is a ngFor-directive so use a ng-container wrapper.

```
<ul *ngIf="this.sessionVar.emptySession == false" class="listTracks" data-simplebar>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of tracksInSession; let i = index">
    <li class="track-item" *ngIf="(this.favSort == false && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == false) || (item.isImported == true && item.isFavorite == false && this.favSort == false && this.impSort == true && this.tracksSort == false) || (item.isImported == true && item.isFavorite == true && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == true && this.tracksSort == false) || (item.isFavorite == true && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == false) || (item.isImported == false && this.favSort == false && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == true) || (item.isFavorite == true && item.isImported == false && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == true)">
      <a href="#" *ngIf="this.favSort == false && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true" [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
      <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isImported == true && item.isFavorite == false && this.favSort == false && this.impSort == true && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
      <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isImported == true && item.isFavorite == true && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == true && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
      <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isFavorite == true && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == false" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
      <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isImported == false && this.favSort == false && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == true" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
      <a href="#" *ngIf="item.isFavorite == true && item.isImported == false && this.favSort == true && this.impSort == false && this.tracksSort == true" (click)="initTrack(item.id, i)" class="grey tracksInSession" [class.hiddenTrack]="item.hiddenFlag == true"  [class.favoriteTrack]="item.isFavorite == true" [class.focus]="isCurrent(i)">{{ item.name}}<br />{{item.creationDate }}</a>
    </li>               
  </ng-container>        
</ul>
```

Comment: there is `item.isFavorite` in `<ng-container>` and this property is out of for loop how you can handle this??

Comment: You are right @Sanoj_V, I edited the snippet so that the for-loop is on the ng-container and the if is on the li-element. Then it is possible to use the item inside the first if-statement of the li-element.